# Converting android color string in runtime into int

Tags: android, type-conversion

`setBackgroundColor()` only takes ints. I don't really know what int equals to what color.
Is there a simple way to convert a string like `#2222FF` on runtime into an `int`?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
int color = Color.parseColor("#2222FF");
```

Comment: But it is giving me a value like -14540033, i mean minus value, so is it true?

Comment: @PareshMayani uh, why do you expect it to be positive? It's o.k. I guess.