# How to set text color of a TextView programmatically?

Tags: android, textview, background-color

How can I set the text color of a TextView to `#bdbdbd` programatically?

Comment: A note about tweaking UI in code, please consider the advantages of seeing the UI in design time, minimizing the runtime changes to minimum.

Comment: Use `textView.setTextColor(textView.getContext().getColor(R.color.white));` to set the text to white or any other color specified in the colors.xml

Answer (score 858, accepted):

Use,..

```
Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd");
```

like,

```
mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
```

Or if you have defined color code in resource's `color.xml` file than

(From API >= 23)

```
mTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.<name_of_color>));
```

(For API < 23)

```
mTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.<name_of_color>));
```

Comment: Why not `0xFFBDBDBD`?

Comment: Color.parseColor("#FFBDBDBD") works as well.

Comment: I had to include the alpha to get it to pass. So, "#ffbdbdbd" rather than "#bdbdbd".

Answer (score 260):

Great answers. Adding [one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)) that loads the color from an Android resources xml but still sets it programmatically:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
```

Please note that from API 23, `getResources().getColor()` is deprecated. Use instead:

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.some_color));
```

where the required color is defined in an xml as:

```
<resources>
  <color name="some_color">#bdbdbd</color>
</resources>
```

**Update:**

> This method was deprecated in API level 23.  Use getColor(int, Theme)
>   instead.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271452/421467).

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble for some reason setting the holo colors, like `tv.setTextColor(color.holo_green_light)`. The text was showing up invisible. So I set the color as a resource in XML like `@android:color/holo_green_light` and set it programmatically with that.

Comment: from API 23 get.Color() is deprecated. 
use instead ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name)

Answer (score 39):

```
yourTextView.setTextColor(color);
```

Or, in your case: `yourTextView.setTextColor(0xffbdbdbd);`

Comment: what does `0xff` mean ? and whats the diff bet `setTextColor(0xffbdbdbd)` and `setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"))` ?

Comment: 0xFFBDBDBD is the hexadecimal reprecentation of an integer, where the different parts represent the amounts of alpha, red, green and blue (0xAARRGGBB) (the 0xff means the alpha is completely white - that is, no transparency). "#bdbdbd" is a string that is parsed to the same integer when passed into the function `parseColor`.

Comment: when you have 4 bytes to define a color, the first byte refers to alpha channel in color, meaning transparency of the color, the remaining bytes refers to red, green and blue; so when you have 0xffbdbdbd is aRGB format and without the first 2 ff is RGB format. Also when you do Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd") this will transform the hexaddecimal formatted string '#bdbdbd' into an integer which will be equivalent to 0xbdbdbd (hex) => 12434877 (dec).

Answer (score 29):

```
TextView tt;
int color = Integer.parseInt("bdbdbd", 16)+0xFF000000;
tt.setTextColor(color);
```

also

```
tt.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt("d4d446", 16)+0xFF000000);
```

also

```
tt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d4d446"));
```

see:

[Java/Android String to Color conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229372/java-android-string-to-color-conversion)

Comment: @ashish.n a change like that should be posted as a new answer, will leave it up to Marek whether he wants to roll it back or not.

Comment: @OGHaza thanks for notification, I'll allow that edit