# Android - DialogFragment change title text color

Tags: android, colors, title, android-dialogfragment

In my application I am changing the DialogFragment title bar background color on runtime. The problem is on different android versions the title text color is changing automatically so it looks sometimes ugly. I want to set a **standard title text color** for all smartphones. 
I followed this sample [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) to build my DialogFragment.

How to set the title text color?

Comment: Simply use a colored TextView in your custom Dialog layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472349/how-to-set-text-color-to-a-text-view-programmatically

Comment: Yes it is the simplest solution.