# How to get a Color from hexadecimal Color String

Tags: android, colors, hex

I'd like to use a color from an hexa string such as `"#FFFF0000"` to (say) change the background color of a Layout.
`Color.HSVToColor` looks like a winner but it takes a `float[]` as a parameter.

Am I any close to the solution at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting android color string in runtime into int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849607/converting-android-color-string-in-runtime-into-int)

Answer (score 679, accepted):

Try `Color` class method:

```
public static int parseColor (String colorString)
```

From [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)):

> Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray'

AndroidX: [String.toColorInt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/graphics/package-summary#tocolorint)

Comment: Anyone knows how to parse `#000` values ?

Comment: Yes, just do: ```if(colorString.length() == 4) { colorString = "#" + StringUtils.repeat(colorString.substring(1, 1), 1) + StringUtils.repeat(colorString.substring(2, 2), 1) + StringUtils.repeat(colorString.substring(3, 3), 1) }```, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: To add to @xdevs23 code, change the if condition to this: `if(colorString.length() == 4 && colorString[0] == '#')`

Comment: Your answer would be better if you don't only show the function, but also how to use it: 
        MyView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#123456");

Comment: int red = colorString.charAt(1) == '0' ? 0 : 255;
int blue = colorString.charAt(2) == '0' ? 0 : 255;
int green = colorString.charAt(3) == '0' ? 0 : 255;
Color.rgb(red, blue, green);

Comment: this return negative int

Comment: To avoid mistakes, don't forget to annotate any method that returns or takes a color int with the [`@ColorInt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/ColorInt.html) support annotation!

Comment: String.toColorInt() method uses Color.parseColor(String) method under the hood.

Answer (score 293):

Try:

```
myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#636161"));
```

Comment: if you are using xamarin.. the code is this Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#636161") with "P" to Upper

Answer (score 62):

This question comes up for a number of searches related to hex color so I will add a summary here.

### Color from int

Hex colors take the form `RRGGBB` or `AARRGGBB` (alpha, red, green, blue). In my experience, when using an `int` directly, you need to use the full `AARRGGBB` form. If you only have the `RRGGBB` form then just prefix it with `FF` to make the alpha (transparency) fully opaque. Here is how you would set it in code. Using `0x` at the beginning means it is hexadecimal and not base 10.

```
int myColor = 0xFF3F51B5;
myView.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```

### Color from String

As others have noted, you can use `Color.parseColor` like so

```
int myColor = Color.parseColor("#3F51B5");
myView.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```

Note that the String must start with a `#`. Both `RRGGBB` and `AARRGGBB` formats are supported.

### Color from XML

You should actually be getting your colors from XML whenever possible. This is the recommended option because it makes it much easier to make color changes to your app. If you set a lot of hex colors throughout your code then it is a big pain to try to change them later.

Android material design has color palates with the hex values already configured.

- [Material Design color styling](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#)
- [Material Design color palette generator](https://www.materialpalette.com/)

These theme colors are used throughout your app and look like this:

*colors.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="primary">#3F51B5</color>
  <color name="primary_dark">#303F9F</color>
  <color name="primary_light">#C5CAE9</color>
  <color name="accent">#FF4081</color>
  <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
  <color name="secondary_text">#757575</color>
  <color name="icons">#FFFFFF</color>
  <color name="divider">#BDBDBD</color>
</resources>
```

If you need additional colors, a good practice to follow is to define your color in two steps in xml. First name the the hex value color and then name a component of your app that should get a certain color. This makes it easy to adjust the colors later. Again, this is in *colors.xml*.

```
<color name="orange">#fff3632b</color>
<color name="my_view_background_color">@color/orange</color>
```

Then when you want to set the color in code, do the following:

```
int myColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_view_background_color);    
myView.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```

### Android Predefined colors

The Color class comes with a number of predefined color constants. You can use it like this.

```
int myColor = Color.BLUE;
myView.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```

Other colors are

- `Color.BLACK`
- `Color.BLUE`
- `Color.CYAN`
- `Color.DKGRAY`
- `Color.GRAY`
- `Color.GREEN`
- `Color.LTGRAY`
- `Color.MAGENTA`
- `Color.RED`
- `Color.TRANSPARENT`
- `Color.WHITE`
- `Color.YELLOW`

### Notes

- A quick way to find hex colors is to open the color chooser dialog in Gimp (or some other photo editing software).
- [Standard opacity levels in Material Design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41121016/3681880)

Answer (score 24):

Convert that string to an `int` color which can be used in `setBackgroundColor` and `setTextColor`

```
String string = "#FFFF0000";
int color = Integer.parseInt(string.replaceFirst("^#",""), 16);
```

The 16 means it is hexadecimal and not your regular 0-9. The result should be the same as

```
int color = 0xFFFF0000;
```

Comment: how can i convert String color ="80000000"; to int color=?

Comment: I think the string version aught to be `#80000000` in which case the int version would be `int color = 0x80000000;`. If that doesn't work then post a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with more details so more people than me will notice it. Keep in mind `#80000000` is a translucent black color.

Comment: I know int would be int color =0x80000000 but my problem is how convert it...But now l'll solved my problem self with int color =parseColor("#"+"80000000");...thanks for reply .

Comment: I got an exception using your code: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "FFFF0000"

Answer (score 16):

It's

```
int color =  Color.parseColor("colorstring");
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF0000"));
```

Answer (score 12):

I use this and it works great for me for setting any color I want.

```
public static final int MY_COLOR = Color.rgb(255, 102, 153);
```

Set the colors using 0-255 for each red, green and blue then anywhere you want that color used just put MY_COLOR instead of Color.BLUE or Color.RED or any of the other static colors the Color class offers.

Just do a Google search for color chart and it you can find a chart with the correct RGB codes using 0-255.

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
int colorInt = Color.parseColor("#FF00FFF0");
bg.setBackgroundColor(colorInt);
```

where bg is a view or layout to which you want to set the background color.

Answer (score 6):

In Xamarin 
Use this

```
Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#F5F1F1"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using 0xFFF000 instead and pass that into the Color.HSVToColor method.

Comment: I would expect that you should replace that third F with a zero. In the OP, I think the first two F characters are used to set the opacity.

Answer (score 4):

If you define a color in your XML and want to use it to change background color or something this API is the one your are looking for:

```
 ((TextView) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_color_here);
```

In my sample I used it for TestView

Answer (score 1):

### I Have created a Complete Answer :

```
    /**
     * Input: Hex Value of ARGB, eg: "#FFFF00FF", "#FF00FF", "#F0F"
     * Output:  Float Color Array with  with red, green,
     * blue and alpha (opacity) values,
     * eg:  floatArrayOf(0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f)
     */
    private fun getFloatArrayFromARGB(argb: String): FloatArray {
        val colorBase: Int = if (argb.length == 4) {
            val red = if (argb[1] == '0') 0 else 255
            val green = if (argb[2] == '0') 0 else 255
            val blue = if (argb[3] == '0') 0 else 255
            Color.rgb(red, green, blue)
        } else {
            Color.parseColor(argb)
        }
        val red = Color.red(colorBase)
        val green = Color.green(colorBase)
        val blue = Color.blue(colorBase)
        val alpha = Color.alpha(colorBase)
        return floatArrayOf(
            red / 255f,
            green / 255f,
            blue / 255f,
            alpha / 255f
        )
    }
```

**Usage**:

```
   private val colorValue = getFloatArrayFromARGB("#F0F")
```

Hope it help somebody

Answer (score 0):

For shortened Hex code

```
int red = colorString.charAt(1) == '0' ? 0 : 255;
int blue = colorString.charAt(2) == '0' ? 0 : 255;
int green = colorString.charAt(3) == '0' ? 0 : 255;
Color.rgb(red, green,blue);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre-defined class to implement directly from hex code to color name so what you have to do is Try key value pair concept simple, follow this code.

```html
String hexCode = "Any Hex code" //#0000FF

HashMap<String, String> color_namme = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        color_namme.put("#000000", "Black");
                        color_namme.put("#000080", "Navy Blue");
                        color_namme.put("#0000C8", "Dark Blue");
                        color_namme.put("0000FF", "Blue");
                        color_namme.put("000741", "Stratos");
                        color_namme.put("001B1C", "Swamp");
                        color_namme.put("002387", "Resolution Blue");
                        color_namme.put("002900", "Deep Fir");
                        color_namme.put("002E20", "Burnham");
                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : color_namme.entrySet()) {
                            String key = (String) entry.getKey();
                            String thing = (String) entry.getValue();
                            if (hexCode.equals(key))
                                Color_namme.setText(thing); //Here i display using textview


                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For kotlin extension function**

```
fun String.toColor(): Int? {
    return if (this.isNotEmpty()) {
        Color.parseColor(this)
    } else {
        null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a delicate Kotlin extension function for a `Jetpack Compose Color`

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

typealias AndroidColor = android.graphics.Color

fun Color.Companion.fromHex(hexColorCode: String): Color {
    val processedColor = hexColorCode.uppercase().removePrefix("#")

    val colorInt = when (processedColor.length) {

        3 -> { // Short RGB format (#RGB)
            val (r, g, b) = processedColor.map { it.toString().repeat(2) }
            AndroidColor.parseColor("#$r$g$b")
        }

        4 -> { // Short ARGB format (#ARGB)
            val (a, r, g, b) = processedColor.map { it.toString().repeat(2) }
            AndroidColor.parseColor("#$a$r$g$b")
        }

        // Standard RGB or ARGB formats
        6, 8 -> AndroidColor.parseColor("#$processedColor")

        else -> {
            Color.Black.hashCode() // Default color if the input is not hex
        }
    }

    return Color(colorInt)
}
```

### Usage:

```
val color = Color.fromHex("#80FF5733")
```