# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color on use static color string

Tags: android, android-drawable

after create this class

```
public class MyColors {
public static String COLOR_APPLICATION = "#FF445FC7";
public static String COLOR_APPLICATION_OPACITY = "#cbb19155";
public static String PRIMARY_COLOR = "#211d1c";
public static String NAVBAR_COLOR = "#0c0c0c";
public static String BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#cbb19155";}
```

then create:

```
public class MyDrawables {

public static Drawable txt_shape = new DrawableBuilder()
        .rectangle().bottomLeftRadius(9).bottomRightRadius(9)
        .solidColor(Color.parseColor(MyColors.COLOR_APPLICATION))
        .build();

public static Drawable text_view_center_shape = new DrawableBuilder()
        .rectangle().solidColor(Color.parseColor("#009c3bbc"))
        .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#9f9f9f")).strokeWidth(1)
        .build();}
```

gettig that exception when using myDrawable like :

```
serviceTxt.setBackground(MyDrawables.txt_shape);
```

what can I do to avoid this crash ?

P.S: application does'nt crashing when create my drawable in activity and use it .

Comment: please post the exception.

Comment: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color  @kelalaka

Comment: can you test with small application with your string? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225185/android-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unknown-color

Answer (score 1):

Use `setBackgroundDrawable()` instead of `setBackground()`
And if you want to set a color as background use `setBackgroundColor()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use static methods like:

```
    public static Drawable txtShape (){
    return new DrawableBuilder()
    .rectangle().bottomLeftRadius(9).bottomRightRadius(9)
    .solidColor(Color.parseColor(MyColors.COLOR_APPLICATION))
    .build();}
```

Or create all shapes you need in **drawable** folder in **res** directory like **.xml** file and refer to them like `R.drawable.text_shape`.

And it will be better to store your colors in **res/values/colors.xml**

Comment: still not working , I won't to create in drawable  because the colors are dynamic in application

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about this, but pls recheck your color string format.
If im not mistaken, color string refers to color hex code which is "#xxxxxx"

```
public class MyColors {
public static String COLOR_APPLICATION = "#FF445FC7"; //<= recheck this
public static String COLOR_APPLICATION_OPACITY = "#cbb19155"; //<= recheck this
public static String PRIMARY_COLOR = "#211d1c"; //<= this is the right format
public static String NAVBAR_COLOR = "#0c0c0c";
public static String BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#cbb19155";} //<= recheck this
```