# 0xFFFF0000 color to rgba(255,255,0,0) conversion

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use Android color picker by duanhong169. Color is given in this format: 0xFFFF0000
and i want to convert it to rgba format in decimal like 255, 255, 0, 0
I try to convert this to String then split it but the conversion output is decimal from all the hex number.
I need decimal from every section.

Comment: Convert it to a long and do bit manipulations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hex color value ( #ffffff ) to integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935057/convert-hex-color-value-ffffff-to-integer-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color?hl=en) class provided by the Android SDK.

Essential what you want to do is this:

```
val color = Color.valueOf(0xFFFF0000)
color.red() * 256
color.green() * 256
color.blue() * 256
color.alpha() * 256
```

You need to multiply by 256 because those functions return a float value between 0 and 1.