# Android Using a Color Resource value in Code

Tags: android, string, colors

I have set a color in my resource colors.xml file. This works fine for TextViews etc

```
<color name="medsListItem">#980000</color>
```

I am building some html/ strings in code and wanted to use same colors as in my app and keep everything well organised

I am using the code below to get the color from the resource above

> String colorToUse = (String) getResources().getString(R.color.medsListItem);

the string produced however is #ff980000
Android is adding **ff** into my string at characters 2 and 3 (or replacing # with #ff at front of string). I can get around this by adding another line in code

> colorToUse = "#" + colorToUse.substring(3, 9);

but I think I am missing something as it is (a) inelegant and (b) I do not know why the **ff** is being added (guessing it is to do with how android handles the color value)

Answer (score 1):

The returned color is in #AARRGGBB format, AA is the alpha value. This is described at the very beginning of this document: [document link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

Comment: In addition to this answer, which is correct. You may find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/android-how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string helpful. The Color class can help you parse the string based hex-color format.