# How to convert Color.RED code into integer values of color in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, colors

In my android projects i set color for PieChart like this

```
public static int[] COLORS = new int[] { Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE };
```

In that **import android.graphics.Color;** have only few colors around 10. I need more color so i tried to set as integer but didn't working. `Color.alpha(16777184)` for light yello color. this code is not working ? how to set here as integer value of color...?

Comment: try answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string

Comment: what this type :16777184?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
Color.parseColor("#FF0000")

int color = 0xFFFF0000;
```

Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd more preffer to use XML file. Suggested solution by Kruba Patel will in fact force developer to remember HEX of color and also redundante of code.

Here XML resource example just call `R.color.color_name` please note that R.color.color_name will return generated int value :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color
        name="color_name"
        >hex_color</color>
</resources>
```