# xamarin set view background color from a hex value

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

How do i programatically set the background color of a view using xamarin from the hex value

For example

```
 view.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00162E");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a Color from hexadecimal Color String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the ParseColor method that takes in a string and returns the integer color.

`view.BackgroundColor = Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#FF6A00");`

Supported formats are:

- #RRGGBB
- #AARRGGBB
- 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray'

Answer (score 2):

From their example.. I think you just need to drop the #.

```
view.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("FF6A00")
```

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/colors/

Depending on your target, you may want to try the parseColor method on the color class instead.

[How to get a Color from hexadecimal Color String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string)

```
public static int parseColor (String colorString)
```

It claims to take hex values :

```
... formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray'
```

Comment: I get an error saying Color does not contain a definition for FromHex.

Comment: You are working cross platform or are you just targeting ios or android or something?

Comment: just targeting android. Im not using Xamarin Forms

Comment: If you are not using forms you may want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string

Answer (score 0):

To change the color programatically of some text in the .xaml file you can do this, in for instance a switch loop:

```
FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.->insert the id/name from the .xaml file <-).SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
break;
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me this:

```
 BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#fcf2e4");
```

My Xamarin.Forms Version: 5.0.0.2012.

I found Code [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.color.fromhex?view=xamarin-forms)

[image: LY]

[image: LY]