# How do I change the background color of calendar dates in MaterialCalendarView

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, calendarview

I'm trying to change the background color of dates using a JSON response I get. But I'm having some difficulty.

Here is my code:

```
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
```

*MainActivty.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {     

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        calbg();
        materialCalendarView.setDateTextAppearance(View.ACCESSIBILITY_LIVE_REGION_ASSERTIVE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        materialCalendarView.setSelectedDate(calendar.getTime());
        materialCalendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {  
        get1 = sharedpreferences.getString(CLIENT, "");       
        materialCalendarView.setDateTextAppearance(getTitleColor());            
        materialCalendarView.setHeaderTextAppearance(R.style.AppTheme_Dark1);   
    }

    private void calbg() {
        // Volley's json array request object
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CALENDAR_DATA,
                new Response.Listener < String > () {  
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject object = null;
                        try {
                            object = new JSONObject(response);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        JSONArray jsonarray = null;
                        try {
                            jsonarray = object.getJSONArray("Table");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

//                        SimpleDateFormatter formatter = new SimpleDateFormatter(); //TODO: update this line with the correct formatter
                        List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String str = obj.getString("eventdate").replaceAll("\\D+","");
                                String upToNCharacters = str.substring(0, Math.min(str.length(), 13));
                                DateFormat timeZoneFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                timeZoneFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8"));

                                Date time = new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(upToNCharacters));
//                                System.out.println(time);
//                                movie.setDate(String.valueOf(timeZoneFormat.format(time)));
//                                String str2 = String.valueOf(timeZoneFormat.format(time));
                                String str1 = obj.optString("eventcolor");
//                                Date date = formatter.parse(str2);
                                int color = Integer.parseInt(str1); //TODO: update this line with the correct code to parse your color
                                Event event = new Event(time, color);
                                events.add(event);
                            }
                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        for (Event event : events) {

                        //Here is the problem in parameter
                            EventDecorator eventDecorator = new EventDecorator(event.getDate(), event.getColor()); 
                            materialCalendarView.addDecorator(eventDecorator);
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                //                hidePDialog();

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map < String, String > getParams() {
                Map < String, String > params = new HashMap < String, String > ();
                params.put(CLIENT, get1);
                return params;
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }}
```

*JSON response*

```
{  
   "Table":[  
      {  
         "userid":4,
         "eventname":"adi",
         "eventdate":"\/Date(1484121600000-0800)\/",
         "eventcolor":"2413AD",
         "autoid":2005
      },


      {  
         "userid":4,
         "eventname":"Mandeep",
         "eventdate":"\/Date(1480924800000-0800)\/",
         "eventcolor":"3A87AD",
         "autoid":2002
      },
      {  
         "userid":4,
         "eventname":"nefv",
         "eventdate":"\/Date(1477465200000-0700)\/",
         "eventcolor":"39AD37",
         "autoid":2
      },

   ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add images of what it looks now in the layout and how you want to look?

Comment: Currently it looks like this and I want to change the back of event dates @Flummox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is to create a `DayViewDecorator` that will take as parameters a `Date` and a color:

```
public class EventDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

    private final Drawable drawable;
    private final CalendarDay day;
    private final int color;

    public EventDecorator(MaterialCalendarView view, Date date, int color) {
        this.day = CalendarDay.from(date);
        this.color = color;
        this.drawable = createTintedDrawable(view.getContext(), color);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        if (this.day.equals(day)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        view.setSelectionDrawable(drawable);
    }

    private static Drawable createTintedDrawable(Context context, int color) {
        return applyTint(createBaseDrawable(context), color);
    }

    private static Drawable applyTint(Drawable drawable, int color) {
        Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, color);
        return wrappedDrawable;
    }

    private static Drawable createBaseDrawable(Context context) {
        return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.day);
    }
}
```

(N.B. I used the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30949446/5241933) to apply the tint. Also, since you didn't specify, I have assumed that the drawable is some kind of image that needs tinting in this way.)

The next step is to create an `Event` class for storing the events you parse from the API call:

```
public class Event {

    private Date date;
    private int color;

    public Event(Date date, int color) {
        this.date = date;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Now we need to add logic to your `onResponse()` method to parse the JSON and add decorators for each event. It is hard to know what exactly to write because you haven't given a sample of the JSON. Your previous questions show that you already know how to parse a `Date` so I think this will be enough. Since you haven't specified, I'll leave it out for now. Also, I'm just appending to your code - I won't try and refactor it much.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    JSONObject object = null;
    try {
        object = new JSONObject(response);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray jsonarray = null;
    try {
        jsonarray = object.getJSONArray("Table");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormatter formatter = new SimpleDateFormatter(); //TODO: update this line with the correct formatter
    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String str2 = obj.optString("eventdate");
            String str1 = obj.optString("eventcolor"); 
            Date date = formatter.parse(str2);
            int color = Integer.parseInt(str1); //TODO: update this line with the correct code to parse your color
            Event event = new Event(date, color);
            events.add(event);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    for (Event event : events) {
        EventDecorator eventDecorator = new EventDecorator(calendarView, event.getDate(), event.getColor());
        calendarView.addDecorator(eventDecorator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some illegal agrument in this line.. EventDecorator eventDecorator = new EventDecorator(event.getDate(), event.getColor());  @David

Comment: Actually @Neo just wait a sec, there's a bug

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: in color parsing

Comment: I wrote that in the answer - you haven't specified the format of the color in your JSON.

Comment: @Neo I'm going to sleep now- there is enough in my answer to get the effect you want. You will have to use your debugging skills and programming skills to get the last mile since I don't have access to your whole project, including the full spec for your JSON. This is only a reasonable expectation. Here is a link for parsing colors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string

Comment: use your programming skills and this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string 

just append a "#" to the start of the String then use the code in the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131494/discussion-between-neo-and-david-rawson).