# Change backgroundcolor of specific date in Androids CalendarView

Tags: java, android

I want to create a calendar in Android Studio, where its possible for every day to select a color (red or green) as background color for this specific day. A few hours of searching and trying out some code I can't find anything about this problem.
Has anyone an idea how the background color of one single day can be changed or if this is not even possible?

Comment: Use a 3rd party lib for this cause Android `CalendarView` is pretty much useless

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237073/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-calendar-dates-in-materialcalendarview

Comment: Do you know a 3td party to do this? I tried the one from @Niles's question, but even with the sample projects I get only errors and it's really bad documented, so I can't find any help how to even use this libary