# How to change the date picker background color in android

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

Need to change the datepicker background color from white to black. Kindly refer the attached image which shown below

How can I modify the color of the background from white to black.

My code is below.

```
public void setListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

       @SuppressLint({"ResourceAsColor", "ResourceType"})
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            Button positive = ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positive.setTextColor(R.color.red);
            positive.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        }
    
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_datepicker, null);
            final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
    
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         
    
            datePicker.setOnDateChangedListener(new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    datePicker.setMaxDate(DateUtils.addYears(c.getTime(), 0).getTime());
                }
    
            });
          return builder.create();
    }
    
     <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/date_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/black_with_corner"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            />
```

[image]

Comment: Try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39407384/5912570)

Comment: The above not worked for the DatePicker

Comment: post your xml here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237073/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-calendar-dates-in-materialcalendarview

Comment: Added there already

Answer (score 1):

```
       <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/black_with_corner"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/ColorBlue"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        />
```

By using backgroundTint u can change the date picker background color - android:backgroundTint="@color/ColorBlue"