# How to change button text based on colour Android studio

Tags: java, android

I can't seem to figure out how I can programmatically change the button text based on the current colour. For example I want to do something similar to the below pseudocode:

```
IF button colour == pink THEN
   set button text to "Pink"
ELSE 
   set button text to "Empty"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the background of the button is a color (not an image, for instance), then you can do it using the following code:

```
int color = ((ColorDrawable) button.getBackground()).getColor();
if(color == Color.rgb(pinkRed, pinkGreen, pinkBlue)) {
   button.setText("Pink");
} else {
   button.setText("Empty");
}
```

Comment: Yes, its a colour. I will it a try and let you know :)

Comment: I would also add that this logic sounds a bit weird. Why would the color change _itself_ have to change the button text? Maybe a better idea is to have whatever original event, which caused the color change, to also change the text as well.

Comment: Good point :) apart from text change, I will also be handling other actions in this if statement. Can I check if its possbile to instead of using rgb to use hex values or normal colour names e.g. color.pink

Comment: @SumOne Yes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string. There is no `Color.PINK`.

Comment: great thanks, works