# Unknown color issue

Tags: android, colors

I'm trying to make a Color att into a global with a class.

my code is this:

```
    public class Global {
    public static boolean active;
    public static int textnormalcolors = Color.parseColor("FF000000");
    public static int textlightcolors = Color.parseColor("FF696969");
    public static int textdarkcolors = Color.parseColor("FFBFBFBF");

    public static int[] normalcolor = {Color.parseColor("#679acf"),Color.parseColor("#3b5e94")};
    public static GradientDrawable NormalGD = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, normalcolor);

    static int[] darkcolor = {Color.parseColor("#213351"),Color.parseColor("#000268")};
    public static GradientDrawable DarkGD = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, darkcolor);

}
```

and the error is this:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color
>           at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:225)
>           at com.example.northlandcaps.crisis_response.Global.(Global.java:8)

Comment: Pass correct format of data to parseColor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a Color from hexadecimal Color String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string hex colors must start with `#`

```
public static int textnormalcolors = Color.parseColor("#FF000000");
```