# Android Hex color to Color

Tags: android, colors, hex

I am facing an Issue converting Hex color `#000` to `Color` or `RGB`. Android `Color.parseColor` doesn't support shortened hex code.

Please suggest the best solution.

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string

Comment: if you use specific #000 you can try with #000000 as This hex color code is also a web safe color which is equal to #000. #000000

Comment: You have to pass 6 digit string to parse the Color. Shortened hex code while give you error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best way is

```
int red = colorString.charAt(1) == '0' ? 0 : 255;
int blue = colorString.charAt(2) == '0' ? 0 : 255;
int green = colorString.charAt(3) == '0' ? 0 : 255;
Color.rgb(red, green,blue);
```