# Android - smarter way to convert color from String to Int

Tags: android

`Color.parseColor("#444444")` works as expected. However, ...
`Color.parseColor("#444")` throws the Exception.

Is there a built-in way for smarter color parsing? Unfortunately, I'm getting them in different formats from Backend.

Comment: Does this post help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm looking for a way to convert String -> Int. And accept string colors in various formats

Comment: Check this one, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [w3_spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-color-20010305#colorunits) for a 3 digits hex color you just need to duplicate each value, something like this

```
#F3A -> #FF33AA
```

since you are getting the value from backend you could try to apply a regex to convert the value before the **Color.parseColor** like this(written in Kotlin)

```
val color = "#FA3"
var colorConverted = color.replace("#([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])".toRegex(), "#$1$1$2$2$3$3")
```

Here's the [link](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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) to the playground, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Alejandro_rios. I' ve written extension based on your answer

```
@ColorInt
fun String.toColor(): Int {
    val colorString = if(this.length == 4) {
        replace("#([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])".toRegex(), "#$1$1$2$2$3$3")
    } else {
        this
    }

    return try {
        colorString.toColorInt()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.d("Error parsing color: $this, e.message = ${e.message}")
        Color.BLACK
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are getting colorCode in string then convert it here

```
 public int getParseColor(String colorCode){
        return Color.parseColor("#"+colorCode);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.