# Android: Color To Int conversion

Tags: android

I'm surprised that `Paint` class has no `setColor(Color c)` method. I want to do the following:

```
public void setColor(Color color) {
/* ... */
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(color); // set color takes only int as a paramter :(
/* ... */
}
```

So any easy way to convert `Color` to `int`?

Comment: android.graphics.Color is a collection of static method. It isn't supposed to be initialized. How did you managed to do this?

Comment: you are right, thanks, please post it again as answer :)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Any `color` parse into `int` simplest two way here:

1) Get System Color

```
int redColorValue = Color.RED;
```

2) Any Color Hex Code as a String Argument

```
int greenColorValue = Color.parseColor("#00ff00")
```

**MUST REMEMBER** in above code `Color` class must be `android.graphics...`!

Answer (score 5):

All the methods and variables in Color are static. You can not instantiate a Color object.

[Official Color Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

> The Color class defines methods for creating and converting color ints.
>
> Colors are represented as packed ints, made up of 4 bytes: alpha, red, green, blue.
>
> The values are unpremultiplied, meaning any transparency is stored solely in the alpha component, and not in the color components.
>
> The components are stored as follows (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue.
>
> Each component ranges between 0..255 with 0 meaning no contribution for that component, and 255 meaning 100% contribution.
>
> Thus opaque-black would be 0xFF000000 (100% opaque but no contributions from red, green, or blue), and opaque-white would be 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: Thanks, I had a bunch of Color declarations in one of my classes and it wansn't working. Now I know why.

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin:

```
val colorInt = Color.Red.toArgb()
```

Comment: Call requires API level 26

Answer (score 2):

Paint DOES have set color function.

```
/**
 * Set the paint's color. Note that the color is an int containing alpha
 * as well as r,g,b. This 32bit value is not premultiplied, meaning that
 * its alpha can be any value, regardless of the values of r,g,b.
 * See the Color class for more details.
 *
 * @param color The new color (including alpha) to set in the paint.
 */
public native void setColor(@ColorInt int color);
```

As an Android developer, I set paint color like this...

```
paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.xxx));
```

I define the color value on color.xml something like...

```
<color name="xxx">#008fd2</color>
```

By the way if you want to the hex RGB value of specific color value, then you can check website like this: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm

I hope this helps ! Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 2):

I tried `Color.toArgb()` and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`R.color.black` or some color are obviously integers.  It needs a RGB value.  You can give your own like `#FF123454` which represents various primary colors

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be **R.color.black**

Also take a look at [Converting android color string in runtime into int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849607/converting-android-color-string-in-runtime-into-int)