# Android: How to Convert String RGB Value to Color to use in View

Tags: java, android, view

I get the following string value from the db: `"rgb(105, 105, 105)"`

I tried `Color.parseColor()` but it wasn't right option.

I try to use it with `view.setBackgroundColor()`

Is there a way for this in Java/Android?

Comment: If you control the format in the database, I'd suggest you change it to one that `parseColor()` will handle; e.g., `#aabbcc`. If not, then you're going to have to parse that yourself, I believe.

Comment: plz search before asking anything https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022364/how-to-convert-rgb-color-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `"rgb(105, 105, 105)"` this format you have to parse it manually.
Try this code:

```
  try{

    String str = "rgb(105, 105, 105)";
    String splitStr = str.substring(str.indexOf('(') + 1, str.indexOf(')'));
    splitString = splitStr.split(",");

    int colorValues[] = new int[splitString.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
        colorValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitString[i].trim());
    }

    int color = Color.rgb(colorValues[0], colorValues[1],colorValues[2]);
    view.setBackgroundColor(color); 

 }catch(Exception ex){

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Short and Simple:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(105, 105, 105));
```

Edit: Mr Abu has given answer with parsing. Its complete answer, use it. I will discard my answer.