# android: how to get ARGB values of the background color for a given textview

Tags: android, background-color, argb

For a given TextView, how to get the Alpha, Red, Green and Blue values (0-255)?

I know how to set
TextView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.argb(a_int, r_int, g_int, b_int));

But how to get?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`ColorDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html#getColor%28%29):

```
ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) textView.getBackground();
int color = cd.getColor();
int alpha = cd.getAlpha();
int red = Color.red(color);
int green = Color.green(color);
int blue = Color.blue(color);
```

[Official Color Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

> The Color class defines methods for creating and converting color ints.
>
> Colors are represented as packed ints, made up of 4 bytes: alpha, red, green, blue.
>
> The values are unpremultiplied, meaning any transparency is stored solely in the alpha component, and not in the color components.
>
> The components are stored as follows (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue.
>
> Each component ranges between 0..255 with 0 meaning no contribution for that component, and 255 meaning 100% contribution.
>
> Thus opaque-black would be 0xFF000000 (100% opaque but no contributions from red, green, or blue), and opaque-white would be
>   0xFFFFFFFF

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6926988/1121804)

Comment: How do I get the R G and B values from 'color' which is an integer?

Comment: Thanks, this is used by this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426573/how-to-transform-hex-color-into-float-0-1/38426718#answer-38426718