# How to transform hex color into float 0-1?

Tags: android, parsing, colors

I need process a hex string value to floating color.

The real color is (in RGBA format)

```
{ 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f }
```

Is green, when 0 is equivalent to 00 and 1 is FF. But need convert the color to 0-255 decimal to calculate the % from 0 to 255 and set the float value.

How to transform by example `#AABBCCFF` to float array?

When parsecolor i have the integer value:

```
Color.parseColor("#AABBCCFF");
```

But how transform the integer to each color in float? red green blue and alpa

Answer (score 5):

I fount the solution:

```
private float[] getFloatArrayFromARGB(String argb){
    int color_base = Color.parseColor(argb);
    int red = Color.red(color_base);
    int green = Color.green(color_base);
    int blue = Color.blue(color_base);
    int alpha = Color.alpha(color_base);

    return new float[]{
            (red / 255f),
            (green / 255f),
            (blue / 255f),
            (alpha / 255f)
    };
}
```

Use:

```
String argb = "#FFFF0000";
float[] color = this.getFloatArrayFromARGB(argb);
GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
```

:D Now use ARGB format to paint 3D objects with OpenGL

Comment: Multiplying and dividing by 100 is not necessary: `(((red * 100) / 255) / 100)` can be simplified to `red / 255f`

Comment: `(((red * 100) / 255) / 100)` also uses integer division and thus would only return 0 or 1

Comment: Richard, i tested, when divide two integer in Java, the framework transform the result from integer to float automaticaly. The result is parsed by `new float[]`, the result return an array of float values. Thanks for simplify the result deleting the "100".